# How to install ffmpeg-php package in cpanel dedicated server without ssh

Tags: php, ffmpeg, cpanel

I am trying to install ffmpeg-php in c-panel without using ssh but i did not found proper resource for steps i have to follow.Any one please provide proper steps i have to follow.

Comment: Do you have access to WHM? You will not be able to install ffmpeg-php from cPanel.

Comment: i am only able to login with Cpanel

Comment: WHM = web host manager. You may access it with yourhost.com/whm and use the administrator credentials. If you have just some hosting account on that server then probably you don't have WHM access and you will not be able to install ffmpeg

Comment: yes i logged in then how can i install

Comment: I suggest asking your hosting provider. The steps depends upon how your current system is configured and you've provided no details there...

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg-php and most of the video conversion tools available are command-line Linux applications with a lot of included libraries and dependencies. So if you're just a shared user (cPanel only) you won't be able to install them.

If you do have access to any sort of shell (try looking for the Java client in cPanel) you can install those manually using rpm or possibly from the repositories with yum.

However, if you find within cPanel that you indeed have no shell access, your only hope is to contact your web host and ask them to install it for you. Sorry!